# How do you find the area under a circle using definite integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, circles

I am studying calculus, and am wondering how to take a definite integral under the area of a circle. As a circle is $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, how do you perform integration with a y in your formula?

My specific problem is $(x)^2 + (y-15)^2 =15^2 \{7.5<x<10\}$

[image]

Comment: isolate y from the equation and integrates in terms of x (it should end in something near $\pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ for a circle centered at origin, the sign depend on the part of circle you geting.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Take the short [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how how to get the most from your time here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your equation and solve for $y$.

$$x^2 + (y-15)^2 = 15^2$$
$$(y-15)^2 = 225 - x^2$$
$$y-15 = \pm \sqrt{225 - x^2}$$
$$y = \pm \sqrt{225 - x^2} + 15$$

We will want to use the *negative* square root because that gives us the bottom half of the circle.  So, $$y = - \sqrt{225 - x^2} + 15.$$

Now you just integrate over the given domain.

$$\int_{7.5}^{10} - \sqrt{225 - x^2} + 15 dx$$

Comment: Thank you! This not only answers my problem, but explains the methodology for problems like it.

Comment: @TonyCorin, you’re welcome, glad I could help!